# iPhone app: How to implement a slider button like the builtin one

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm talking about the "slide to unlock" button on iPhone. Any ideas how to go about implementing one in my own iPhone app? I don't see it as a control in IB, or maybe I just missed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a provided control, you'll have to roll your own. This shouldn't be too hard, just use the touch methods (see UIResponder) to provide functionality to the view.